# PHP - How to Add a Tag for Each Selected Checkbox in a Form

Tags: php, forms, api, customization

Does anyone know how to **add a tag for each selected checkbox** with pure PHP? My form is integrated with the [Active Campaign API](https://www.activecampaign.com/api/example.php?call=contact_tag_add).( You don't have to be familiar with the API)

Everything is working great, but the key (tag) returns one string with all values  (interests) together, separated by column.

```
  $interests_val = $_POST['interests_val'];

  $contact = array(
    "email"                           => $user_info->user_email,
    "tags[0]"                         => "[Interest] ".implode(", ", $interests_val),

  );
```

Instead, I would like to add one tag for each selected value, or checkbox. Is there a way to execute this more efficiently? I have more than 20 checkboxes.

```
 $interests_val = $_POST['interests_val'];

  $contact = array(
    "email"                           => $user_info->user_email,
    "tags[0]"                         => "[Interest] ".$interests_val[0]),
    "tags[1]"                         => "[Interest] ".$interests_val[1]),
    "tags[2]"                         => "[Interest] ".$interests_val[2]),

  );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a loop over your `$interests_val`, and after creating the `$contact` array with the fixed values (`email` in this case), create additional keys dynamically:

```
$interests_val=implode($_POST['interests_val']);

$contact = array("email"=> $user_info->user_email);
foreach($interests_val as $key=>$value){
   $contact["tags{$key}"] = "[Interest] {$value}";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not seem to work. It doesn't return the tags. Is there any other way to get this right?